# EntityManager - Only one expression can be declared

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a SQL query. When I run this query on datebase I've get returned results. But when I will put this query in Java (EntityManager) I've got a exception:

> Only one expression can be declared in a SELECT clause of a subquery.

Could you write me what is wrong?

SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct d.pId
FROM Document d
WHERE d.date>= :date1 AND d.date< :date2 AND d.ro = :ro AND
      d.adressId IN (SELECT nvl(a.previd, a.id) id FROM Adress a where a.id= :aid)
```

Comment: Ok. A use Oracle datebase

Answer (score 0):

Your query is only returning one row from the subquery, so it wouldn't seem to generate that error.

Does changing the query to `exists` fix the problem?

```
SELECT distinct d.pId
FROM Document d
WHERE d.date >= :date1 AND d.date < :date2 AND d.ro = :ro AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Adress a
              WHERE a.id = :aid AND
                    (d.adressId = a.previd OR
                     (d.adressId = a.id AND a.previd IS NULL)
                    )
             );
```

Comment: I`ve got other exception:
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "T2"."ID"."T2"."ID": invalid identifier
Querty = "... (SELECT ? FROM DATA.ADRESS t2 WHERE ((t2.ID = ?) AND ((t1.ADRESS_ID = t2.PREV_ID.t2.ID) OR ((t1.ADRESS_ID = t2.ID.t2.ID) AND (t2.PREV_ID IS NULL))))) )")"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct d.pId 
   FROM Document d
   WHERE d.date >= :date1 AND d.date < :date2 AND d.ro = :ro AND
      d.adressId IN (SELECT nvl(a.previd, a.id) FROM Adress a where a.id = :aid)
```